# 'This method must return a result of type int' Java?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double arr[] = {1,-6.3,9000,67.009,1.1,0.0,-456,6,23,-451.88};

    ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     List.add(1);
     List.add((int) -6.3);
     List.add(9000);
     List.add((int) 67.009);
     List.add((int)1.1);
     List.add((int)0.0);
     List.add(-456);
     List.add(6);
     List.add(23);
     List.add((int)451.88);
}

public static int ArrayListMax(ArrayList List)
{

    for (int i=0; i<List.size(); ++i)
    {
        System.out.println(List.get(i));
    }
```

The error is in:

```
  public static int ArrayListMax(ArrayList List)
```

This is probably a very nooby mistake, but I'm new to Java so forgive me.

Any help please?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I want the ArrayListMax method to print the size of the List!

Comment: Declare the method as `public static void ArrayListMax(ArrayList List)`, since you are not returning anything.

Comment: You are not showing your complete code of `ArrayListMax`. You probably have written a wrong return statement or you missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to get the maximum value in your `List` in the method `arrayListMax`, you need to return an integer in accordance with your method signature, which the error is telling you

```
This method must return a result of type int
```

Instead of printing all the values in the list, you could do:

```
public static int arrayListMax(List<Integer> List) {
   return Collections.max(list);
}
```

---

Use [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm). Method & variable names begin with a lowercase letter. Using this approach helps avoid confusion between instances & types (e.g. in the case of `List` in the `main` method).

Answer (score 1):

Either add a `return` statement to your `ArrayListMax()` method that returns an `int` or change the method signature from `public static int` to `public static void`. And add a closing `}` to the method too.

Also, you shouldn't use `List` as a name for the argument to that method because it's the name of an interface that you're actually importing in this code. The convention in java is for variable names and method names to begin with a lowercase letter (camel case) and class names to begin with an uppercase letter (pascal case).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this method:

```
public static int ArrayListMax(ArrayList List)
{

    for (int i=0; i<List.size(); ++i)
    {
       System.out.println(List.get(i));
    }
}
```

You are not returning from this method, you must return of type int to solve that error. Since you have specified int as return type.

Answer (score 0):

You created the function as returning a result

```
public static int ArrayListMax(ArrayList List)
```

In order to remove your problem, if you need not return anything, write

```
public static void ArrayListMax(ArrayList List)
```

`void` means you do not want the method to return a result.

Answer (score 0):

if you are just printing out values the signature should be public static void ArrayListMax(ArrayList List).

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you are not returning anything with `ArrayListMax` method even if you have set its retun type to `int`. Either return `void` as you are directly printing from the list.

**Second,** even if you set the correct return type to `ArrayListMax` method, you will still need to call that method in the `main` method as below:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double arr[] = {1,-6.3,9000,67.009,1.1,0.0,-456,6,23,-451.88};

    ArrayList<Integer> List = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     List.add(1);
     List.add((int) -6.3);
     List.add(9000);
     List.add((int) 67.009);
     List.add((int)1.1);
     List.add((int)0.0);
     List.add(-456);
     List.add(6);
     List.add(23);
     List.add((int)451.88);
     YourClassNameInWhichMethodIs.ArrayListMax(List);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a return statement as Methode is returning an int type value.